# Return the maximum value of a row of a matrix without considering the diagonal coefficients

Tags: java, arrays, max

I have a the two-dimensional array :

```
0. | 0.0 | -0.8980387129971331 | -0.8900869793075101 | -0.8906789098245378 | 1.0104911316104093 | -0.8816392828513628
1. | -0.8998803800424156 | 0.0 | -0.8894871457733221 | -0.8897044897987794 | 1.1079409359304297 | -0.7105118305961893
2. | -0.8889556072705933 | -0.8924868056899387 | 0.0 | 1.1083728720261286 | 1.0098247893112775 | 1.099113864022297
3. | -0.8808751963282109 | 0.9280169284175466 | -0.8891630366886065 | 0.0 | -0.69121432906078 | -0.7092216479617963
4. | -0.8986589499572509 | -0.8921590617526629 | -0.8891630366344203 | -0.7057342552186525 | 0.0 | -0.7075934709028173
5. | -0.8988751964282238 | -0.8981045503211356 | -0.8891659511135326 | 1.0907466603012215 | 1.1072644730546006 | 0.0
```

And I want to get **`the maximum of a line`** without considering the **`diagonal coefficients`**.

I'm using the following funtion :

```
public static int max(double[] array) {
    int max = 0;
    double old = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > old) {
            max = i;
            old = array[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

But for example for the **`4th line`** it returns me the value **`0.0`** while I want it to return: **`-0.7057342552186525`**.

It must return the **`maximum`** among **`all the values`** ​​except the **`value of the column 4`**.

**EDIT**

```
public static int max2(double[][] array ,int k) {
     int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    double old = array[0][0];
    
        for(int j =0 ; j<array.length; j++ ) {
            if(k==j) {
                continue;
            }
        if (array[k][j] > old) {
            max = j;
            old = array[k][j];
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

I'm gettinh this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2147483648
```

Comment: Your code doesn't handle a 2-dimensional array, why?

Comment: You array is not two dimensional, as you pass `double[]` and you iterate it like a one dimensional array as well, without any consideration to width. If you actually use a 2D array, then you can iterate it with an outer and an inner loop and ignore elements where index `i` equals index `j`, as I assume those are your diagonal elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is allowed to Java Stream API, the maximum value in an array of doubles can be found like this (excluding the index of the row):

```java
public static Double max(double[] row, int rowId) {
    return IntStream
        .range(0, row.length)     // analog of for-loop
        .filter(i -> i != rowId)  // skip "diagonal" index
        .mapToDouble(i -> row[i]) // get value in the row by index
        .max()                    // find max OptionalDouble
        .getAsDouble();           // get double value
}
```

Similar non-stream version would look as follows (return `null` if no maximum value is available):

```java
public static Double maxWithLoop(double[] row, int rowId) {
    Double max = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        if (i == rowId) {
            continue;
        }
        if (null == max || max < row[i]) { 
            max = row[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Test

```
double[][] data = {
    { 0.0, -0.8980387129971331, -0.8900869793075101, -0.8906789098245378, 1.0104911316104093, -0.8816392828513628},
    { -0.8998803800424156, 0.0, -0.8894871457733221, -0.8897044897987794, 1.1079409359304297, -0.7105118305961893},
    { -0.8889556072705933, -0.8924868056899387, 0.0, 1.1083728720261286, 1.0098247893112775, 1.099113864022297},
    { -0.8808751963282109, 0.9280169284175466, -0.8891630366886065, 0.0, -0.69121432906078, -0.7092216479617963},
    { -0.8986589499572509, -0.8921590617526629, -0.8891630366344203, -0.7057342552186525, 0.0, -0.7075934709028173},
    { -0.8988751964282238, -0.8981045503211356, -0.8891659511135326, 1.0907466603012215, 1.1072644730546006, 0.0}
};

int i = 0;
for (double[] row : data) {
    System.out.printf("max in row #%d: % .4f%n", i, max(row, i++));
}
```

Output

```
max in row #0:  1.0105
max in row #1:  1.1079
max in row #2:  1.1084
max in row #3:  0.9280
max in row #4: -0.7057
max in row #5:  1.1073
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You return an index instead of element
2. You return an int instead of double
3. You start an array from [1]

It looks like you want to call max() on each line of your two-dimensional array.
So that is the reason why we have the trouble: You don't know which element is diagonal coefficient. If in your task you are **absolutely sure** that there are no elements equal to 0.0 except for diagonal coefficient, you can use the next code, calling the max(yourTwoDimensionalArray[lineToFindTheMaximumIn]):

```
public static double max(double[] array) {
    double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i]!=0) max = Double.max(max, array[i]);
    }
    return max;
}
```

**Also please note that arrays start from [0] not from [1]**

As you can see, max(yourArray[3]) returns -0.7057342552186525 for 4th line in your array.

I hope it will help you, if not, leave a comment and I'll try to explain you more

Comment: thank you for your help , please check My EDIT